Compressed sensing with FFT basis
Trying to implement compressed sensing with FFT in Matlab. I have implementet compressed sensing for time series with descret cosine transform sucsessfully, but changing dct to fft and idct to ifft is not enough since the code give me only zeros.
%% Generate signal, DCT of signal
n = 4000;    % points in high resolution signal
t = linspace(0, 4000, n); 
x = 0.5*cos(2* 0.008 * pi * t) + 0.5*cos(2* 0.016 * pi * t) + 0.5*cos(2* 0.064 * pi * t) + 0.5*cos(2* 0.256 * pi * t); 
xt = fft(x); % Fourier transformed signal
PSD = abs(real(xt)).^2/((n-1)*1);  % Power spectral density

%% Randomly sample signal
p = 128; % num. random samples, p=n/32
perm = round(rand(p, 1) * n);
y = x(perm); % compressed measurement

%% Solve compressed sensing problem
Psi = dct(eye(n, n));  % build Psi
Theta = Psi(perm, :);  % Measure rows of Psi

%s = cosamp(Theta,y',10,1.e-10,10); % CS via matching pursuit
%% L1-Minimization using CVX
cvx_begin;
    variable s(n); 
    minimize( norm(s,1) ); 
    subject to 
        Theta*s == y';
cvx_end;

xrecon = idct(s);      % reconstruct full signal

The code work fine with DCT but give zeros when changing basis to FFT.
Any idea of how to implement FFT here?
